# Pyspark: adding parameter to a filter function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Please, I would appreciate some help: I need to add a parameter to this function but this syntax is not correct:

```
val input_parameter = 100
df_filtered = (df.filter(( (F.col('LOCID') != F.col('LOCID2') ) & 
                           (F.col('distance') <= F.col('RADIUSINMETERS') + F.col('RADIUSINMETERS2') + input_parameter)  
                        ))
              )
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe `F.lit(input_parameter)`?

Comment: Thank you! I got it just removing val, it is working now

Answer (score 1):

Spark needs to know that you are passing a variable, in order to do that we need to ensure we are passing within **`lit()`** function , from the documentation

> Creates a Column of literal value.

more read [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lit-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Thanks, finally I could get it just removing `val` from the line, thanks!